# Сделать проверку от создания 2-х и более потоков

Tags: c++, winapi

Как бы вам объяснить что я делаю.

Я делаю что-то вроде оверлейного меню (работает внешне, поверх игры), так вот в этом оверлейном меню есть некоторые функции, которые заблокированы в игре.

Так вот, я сделал систему конфигураций, то есть можно сохранить параметры оверлейного меню, и загрузить параметры, и есть одно но, при загрузке 1 функция имеет true, и создает вот такой поток:

```
if (bhop)
{
    BHOP = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, bhop_thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

В итоге, если я два раза загружу конфиг, то он создаст два потока, и в конечном итоге выключение не поможет. Как этого избежать?

Вот делал такую проверку:

```
HANDLE BHOP = NULL;
if (bhop && !BHOP)
{
    BHOP = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, bhop_thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
else if (!bhop && BHOP)
{
    TerminateThread(BHOP, 0);
    CloseHandle(BHOP);
}
```

Но после повторного запуска bool bhop имеет true, и HANDLE BHOP тоже имеет true, хотя я закрыл поток.

Comment: А почему им не быть `true`? Вы где-то выставляете их в другие значения?

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи в стандартной библиотеке есть функция [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) (и специальный флаг [std::once_flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag)). Как понятно из названия, функция запускает поток только один раз, даже если вызывается несколько раз (и даже, возможно, из разных потоков).